# Jquery with many buttons call a function with sending different parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple code but cant get the values of my input text. Is there any way to do this?

```
<?php

    for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
        echo ('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="vec" id="vec'.$i.'" value="'.$listOfData0[$i].'">');
        echo ('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="drv" id="drv'.$i.'" value="'.$listOfData1[$i].'">');
        echo ('<button type="button" name="updateVecButton" id="updateVecButton" value="'.$vec[$i].','.$vell[$i].'" onclick="refreshVec("'.$i.'","'.$vell[$i].'");"></button>');
    }
?>

<script>
function refreshVec(i,vell){
    alert (i + " "+ vell);
    var value0 = $("#vec"+i).val();
    var value1 = $("#drv"+i).val();
    alert (value0 + " " + value1);
}

</script>
```

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: yes. I have also some other functions with JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is

```
$(this).prop("value");
```

The .val() is another thing. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You garbled the HTML by also using double quotes in the onclick attribute. You should see it in the generated HTML.

Try

```
echo ('<button type="button" name="updateVecButton" id="updateVecButton" value="'.$vec[$i].','.$vell[$i].'" onclick="refreshVec(\''.$i.'\',\''.$vell[$i].'\');"></button>');
```

instead of

```
echo ('<button type="button" name="updateVecButton" id="updateVecButton" value="'.$vec[$i].','.$vell[$i].'" onclick="refreshVec("'.$i.'","'.$vell[$i].'");"></button>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call as an array of inputs. Like,

```
  echo('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="vec[]" id="vec'.$i.'" value="'.$listOfData0[$i].'">');
  echo('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="drv[]" id="drv'.$i.'" value="'.$listOfData1[$i].'">');
  echo('<button type="button" name="updateVecButton[]" id="updateVecButton" onclick="refreshVec("'.$i.'","'.$vell[$i].'");"/>'.$vec[$i].','.$vell[$i].'</button>');
```

Change name="vec" and name="drv" As name="vec[]" and name="drv[]"

In your  ( 
`onclick="refreshVec("'.$i.'","'.$vell[$i].'");`

you should change as

`onclick="refreshVec(\''.$i.'\',\''.$vell[$i].'\');`

As I think, the reason is you passing parameters with string values.

Comment: I  try but there is no problem with my button example. I get the parameters in my function I write an alert at the beginning of my function and see both parameters. But there is problem with values. 
var value0 = $("#vec"+i).val();
    var value1 = $("#drv"+i).val();

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but there is space present between `refreshVec(`**`" 2"`**`,"2")`.

This makes string like `" 2"` and not `"2"`

That's why ID selector is selecting wrong id containing that space and you are not getting expected output

I corrected it and it is working now:

```
echo '<button onclick="refreshVec(\''.$i.'\',\''.$vell[$i].'\');">'.$vec[$i].','.$vell[$i].'</button>';
```

**Note**: buttons don't have attribute like `value`. You should put text inside `<button>` tag

Comment: I get the parameters inside the function. I get this fault on console  index.php?p=allVec:406 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at refreshVec (index.php?p=allVec:406)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php?p=allVec:348)